# Deprecated ReflectionParameter::getClass() Errors After Switching Back to Laravel 5.5 from Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, deprecated

After switching from my Laravel 6 branch back to my Laravel 5.5 branch, I'm encountering several deprecation errors related to the `ReflectionParameter::getClass()` method in my application. The errors are as follows:

> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in
> /private/var/www/finconnect/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 811
> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is
> deprecated in
> /private/var/www/finconnect/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 885

I have attempted multiple solutions to resolve these errors, including:

Clearing various Laravel caches:

```
php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:clear, php artisan view:clear
```

Removing the vendor directory and reinstalling dependencies:

```
rm -rf vendor/, composer clearcache, composer dump-autoload -o
```

The documentation suggests that `ReflectionParameter::getClass()` is deprecated as of PHP 8, recommending the use of `ReflectionParameter::getType()` instead. However, I'm currently running PHP 7.3, as confirmed by `php -v`, and my Valet setup appears to be healthy.

`PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Dec 27 2023 06:53:55) ( NTS )`

| Check | Success? |
| --- | --- |
| Is Valet fully installed? | Yes |
| Is Valet config valid? | Yes |
| Is Homebrew installed? | Yes |
| Is DnsMasq installed? | Yes |
| Is Dnsmasq running? | Yes |
| Is Dnsmasq running as root? | Yes |
| Is Nginx installed? | Yes |
| Is Nginx running? | Yes |
| Is Nginx running as root? | Yes |
| Is PHP installed? | Yes |
| Is linked PHP (php@7.3) running? | Yes |
| Is linked PHP (php@7.3) running as root? | Yes |
| Is valet.sock present? | Yes |

I'm puzzled by these deprecation notices since they're supposed to only apply to PHP 8 and above. Has anyone faced similar issues when working with Laravel 5.5 on PHP 7.3, or does anyone have insights on how to resolve these deprecation warnings? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`ReflectionParameter::getClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php) was deprecated in PHP 8.0. Laravel 5.5 is too old (it was released before PHP 8).

Comment: Even though this shouldn't happen with valet, try to run `phpinfo()` from within the app to see what version it is actually running on. `php -v` only shows what PHP version is running for CLI.

Comment: `I'm puzzled by these deprecation notices since they're supposed to only apply to PHP 8 and above.` ... I don't know why some call these `errors`, as the app would not run at all if they were, but anyway, you have a version _before_ PHP 8, and those messages indicate that a PHP function used somewhere in the code is no longer supported _IN A FUTURE_, i.e. higher PHP version, NOT the version currently being used.